# GCM Send-to-Sync vs. Messages with Payload

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

When sending Send-to-Sync messages to many many recipients,
Should i be worried that all or most the devices will then come to sync at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

If you send a message to multiple devices at the same time and the message causes them to access your server,  your server might be hit by many requests at the same time.

If that's a problem,  you might spread the server load by not sending all the notifications at the same time. Another option is to send the notifications with 'delay_while_idle=true', which will wait for devices to become active before delivering the notifications, thus reducing the number of devices hitting your server at the same time.

Finally, your devices should call the server using async calls,  so that even if the server is busy,  the app won't appear stuck while waiting for the reply.

Comment: so would it not be better for me to send all the required information as part of the message instead of using "send to sync"?

Comment: @epeleg That depends on the size of the required information, as well as its importance. Since GCM does not guarantee delivery, you shouldn't rely on it completely. Your app should still be able to sync with the server in case some of the notifications don't reach the device.

Comment: That is obvious, I just want to notify the user that he has a new message waiting for him within the application. if notification failes there will not be a notification... but when the user opens the app he will see the latest messages anyway..

Comment: @epeleg Well, in that case, you can send the full data in the notification if it's not longer than 4k. Just make sure to use a different `collapse_key` for each notification, in order not to lose messages when the device is disconnected from the internet. Regardless to whether you send the full data or just send to sync, you should design your server to handle high load (which can still occur if many users start your app at the same time).